# Create hollow sphere with pie having any radius using CSS?

Tags: css

I am just trying to make a hollow sphere with another colored pie which can have any radius. Searched alot but find some things `border-radius` property which i know already but `clip: rect(top, right, bottom, left)`. How can i use that? I searched for tutorials for it but tutorials are little messy and incomplete.

What Exactly effect is?

[Link To Website](http://www.awwwards.com)

See How that four colored hollow sphere look like.

And stackoverflow also does not consists of any question like this.

Comment: You would like to create just like those yellow-red-blue circles?

Comment: nah man i think duplicate of that one and also a tutorial which explain what is done and what is not ;)

Comment: I just learned a new property from your question `clip` and I already figured out what needs to be done, so why I would like to answer it.

Comment: what is this "why I would like to answer it" ? can you explain.

Comment: @AliBassam what can i do is only guarantee you +25 reputation if and only if it fulfill requirememts.

Comment: Sorry I meant "So That's why I would Like to Answer it"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Create that Pie Effect, you must have 2 divs.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="master">
    </div>
    <div id="slave">
    </div>
</div>
```

The First div is the original sphere, it can be done purely with `border-radius`.

[image]

```
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
width:70px;
height:70px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:10px;
border-color:#573;
```

The Second div will have the lighter color, again purely with `border-radius`.

[image]

```
-webkit-border-radius: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
width:70px;
height:70px;
border-style:solid;
border-width:10px;
border-color:#99FF33;
```

Then we use `clip:rect(0px,50px,50px,0px);`.

[image]

Now we must only fix the positioning, using `postion:relative;` and `position:absolute;`

**CSS**

```
#parent
{
    position:relative;
}
#master
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:10px;
    border-color:#573;
}
#slave
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:10px;
    border-color:#99FF33;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    clip:rect(0px,50px,50px,0px);
}
```

CHECK IT OUT - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/Af8Hh/)**.

[image]

Check this [Border Radius Generator](http://mistercss.blogspot.com/p/border-radius-generator_31.html) (used to make circles).

**UPDATE**

I found a way to decrease and increase but it requires 2 slaves, Same CSS properties.

If the percentage is 50% and above, we must hide the second slave, and decrease or increase the `bottom` of the first slave.

`clip:rect(0px,50px,20px,0px);`

[image]

`clip:rect(0px,50px,100px,0px);`

[image]

Now when half of the circle is filled, we must `show` the second slave. To decrease it and increase it, we should change the `top`.

`clip:rect(60px,100px,100px,0px);`

[image]

`clip:rect(20px,100px,100px,0px);`

[image]

Check it out - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/wvxP5/)

```
clip:rect(top,right,bottom,left);
```

Comment: what if i want to increment lighter div ?

Comment: how can let that lighter div to increase but not change its position as in that web ?

Comment: It won't change its position, the only thing you need to do is to change the `top,right,bottom,left` in `clip` so you increase it or decrease it.

Comment: well, that is the only thing which confuses me. You can see how it animates in that web. And when i try to do ? what happens see: http://jsfiddle.net/Af8Hh/1/ that #slave div does not increase if i also give a large value

Comment: well, it still doesn't animate as i want because the animation there is smooth and does not have a single shape problem :D still thanks for your precious time :D

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for your effort!