# CSS3 spinner, preloader

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms, css-shapes

I would like to build a animated spinner with CSS3.
It should behave like this :

[image: CSS spinner state 1]
[image: CSS spinner state 2]
[image: CSS spinner state 3]
[image: CSS spinner state 4]

After the last state it should start again like in the first state.

I managed to create circles using the technique explained here :  [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776661/create-hollow-sphere-with-pie-having-any-radius-using-css)

Now, how can **I animate the spinner between the described states?** I do not know how to animate the clip-rect property. I also guess that it would behave better with a clip-poly instead (a triangle maybe) but I can't animate that either.

Comment: Have you tried? If yes, please post your code. Also, what would be the state after the 4th image?

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tTW65/). It is an adapted version of the demo provided in [this](https://medium.com/@andsens/radial-progress-indicator-using-css-a917b80c43f9) link. I think there are better ways to achieve this, but if you don't get any further answers, I will add this as an answer.

Comment: Or check this [link](http://blog.invatechs.com/round_progress_bar_with_html5_css3_and_javascript).

Comment: Thank you. Your last link is definitely what I was looking for. I hope it's going to work on mobile devices and it will be smooth enough. I'll tell you once I tested it everywhere

Comment: I finally accepted the answer below because it's a cleaner solution. thanks anyway for your very interesting techniques

Comment: No worries mate. That answer was better and thats part of the reason why I had not posted mine as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### CSS3 spinner

This CSS preloader uses keyframe animations and `transform-rotate` *CSS3* properties to make the circle and the filling color.

This spinner is responsive.

```css
.sp1 {
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #557733;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.sp:before,
.sp:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #99FF33;
}

.sp1:after {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 6;
}

.sp1:before {
  background-color: inherit;
  z-index: 5;
}

.sp2:before {
  z-index: 4;
  -webkit-animation: spin1 3s linear infinite;
          animation: spin1 3s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
          transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.sp2:after {
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 6;
  -webkit-animation: spin2 3s linear infinite;
          animation: spin2 3s linear infinite;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
          transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
  0%         { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50%, 100%  { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); }
   
}

@keyframes spin1 {
  0%         { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  50%, 100%  { transform: rotate(180deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); opacity: 0; }
  49.99% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  opacity: 1; }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes spin2 {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); opacity: 0; }
  49.99% { opacity: 0; }
  50% { transform: rotate(0deg); opacity: 1; }
  100% { transform: rotate(180deg); opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="sp sp1">
  <div class="sp sp2"></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Mwjn9/)