# CSS3/Canvas - loader/spinner/preloader

Tags: css, preloader

I would like to make a CSS3 (preferred) or canvas spinner like this one http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Mwjn9/

But when the light green circle is complete, instead of starting again, I would like the circle to be filled with dark green (in the same way it was filled with light green), and then start again.

Basically, circle starts with color A, is filled with Color B, filled with color A and it starts again.

How can I achieve this ?

I tried of editing this part in different ways but couldn't achieve it.

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin1 {
    0%   { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); }
    50%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); }
}
@keyframes spin1 {
    0%   { transform:rotate(0deg); }
    50%  { transform:rotate(180deg); }
    100% { transform:rotate(180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin2 {
    0%   { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:0; }
    49.99%   { opacity:0; }
    50%  { -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:1; }
    100% { -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);opacity:1; }
}
@keyframes spin2 {
    0%   { transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:0; }
    49.99%   { opacity:0; }
    50%  { transform:rotate(0deg);opacity:1; }
    100% { transform:rotate(180deg);opacity:1; }
}
```

Comment: do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/d7vKd/?

Comment: yes, but it should start again when its finished but when inverted colors

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/q/24484727/1811992

Comment: Yes web tiki, same problem but different spinner. I managed to do it with canvas though. I'm still having a hard time with css3 anims

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with canvas, using two arcs

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

and animating them
http://jsfiddle.net/Rayjax/0ah48htn/1/

If someone comes up with a CSS3 solution (canvas is slow on mobiles) I'm glad to take it