# Firefox does not animate SVG size changes

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox, svg

We've implemented a web page with an SVG illustration that's manipulated by Javascript code. It's working in all major browsers. The CSS *transition* attribute is used to animate the transitions between states:

```
svg rect {
   transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```

It works in all major browser. However, Firefox only animates the color change but not the change in size and position of the SVG element.

I've set up a minimal example in JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gvswzghf/. It grows and shrinks a rectangle and changes the color at the same time.

Is this a know limitation of Firefox? Or how can this be fixed?

---

HTML:

```
<div>
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
    <rect x="50" y="200" width="300" height="100" fill="#000"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
<p>
  <button id="bt-grow">Grow</button>
  <button id="bt-shrink">Shrink</button>
</p>
```

Style sheet:

```
svg rect {
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

svg {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
var rect = document.getElementById("svg").children[0];

document.getElementById("bt-grow").addEventListener("click", function () {
  rect.setAttribute("y", "0");
  rect.setAttribute("height", 300);
  rect.setAttribute("fill", "#090");
  return false;
});

document.getElementById("bt-shrink").addEventListener("click", function () {
  rect.setAttribute("y", "200");
  rect.setAttribute("height", 100);
  rect.setAttribute("fill", "#000");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: hm, correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you setting HTML attributes in your JS, not CSS properties? I'm somewhat surprised this works in *any* browser

Comment: I've also tried it with `rect.y.baseVal.value = 0;` instead of `rect.setAttribute("y", "0");`. But the behavior is exactly the same. How would you change the position and size from Javascript?

Comment: It's SVG, which has its own rules when it comes to styling (it only respects limited CSS, having a lot of element properties for styling instead, since it's a graphics language) so you'd use SVG animation code. Something like http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-animation.html - create an `<AnimationTransform>` (either as initial dummy or using `document.createElementNS()` with the SVG namespace), then append it to the element you need to animate.

Comment: The kind of animations you refer to are SMIL animations. They are deprecated. Chrome e.g. warns: "SVG's SMIL animations ('animate', 'set', etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead."

Comment: Aye, that's what they say, so you might be stuck with having to do both. http://caniuse.com/#search=smil tells us that FF still fully supports it, as do Blink/WebKit-based browsers, for the next quarter year at the very least (although they give you that warning) so you might have to do JS feature detection to decide which of the two to go with. I don't know if there's a bug for Firefox around making CSS transitions work for SVG element properties (though I expect they want that to be [transition-property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property))

Comment: I didn't know that property. Even though Firefox seems to know it (it's not crossed out in the inspector), it doesn't change anything. It's still not working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's the info I was looking for. Why don't you create a proper answer for it? I'll accept it then.

Comment: For SVG animation from IE9+, use javascript (or jQuery) coding to update the '<rect>' attributes. Here's an example of circle animation, concept is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178095/svg-circle-animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot animate attributes with CSS animation and in SVG 1.1 (which Firefox implements) y and width are attributes. In SVG 2 they are CSS properties. Chrome (and its clone Opera) is currently the only UA to have implemented this part of SVG 2.

For Firefox support you'll have to use SMIL. There are [polyfills](https://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation) to add SMIL support to Chrome.