# Text field in SVG viewbox does not rotate

Tags: css, svg, text, css-transforms

```css
        .pie{
            border-radius:50%;
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
        .pie .background{
            fill:none;
            stroke:#eaeaea;
            stroke-width:3;
            stroke-dasharray:100.53 100.53;
        }
         .pie .chart{
            fill:none;
            stroke:#f73319;
            stroke-width:3;
            stroke-dasharray:0 100.53;
            animation: 2s linear slice ;
            animation-fill-mode:forwards;

        }
         .pie text{
            font-size:6px;
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;
         }
        @keyframes slice{
            to{stroke-dasharray:75.39 100.53;}
        }
```

```html
<body>
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
    <circle class="background" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%">

    </circle>
       <circle class="chart" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%">

    </circle>
        <text x="32" y="32">
        75%
    </text>
</svg>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pw2c1rss/3/)

I have a `<text>` field in my svg viewbox. The viewbox has been rotated by `-90deg`, but for obvious reasons I want my text to be rotated back. However only Firefox seems to take into account the above code and rotate the text. Any reason why the other browsers don't? How do I write it correctly so that it does rotate?

Comment: Try this answer that was written a few years ago, without all the CSS complexity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178095/svg-circle-animation/26183645#26183645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to rotate the whole SVG and then rotate the `<text>` back to compensate.  Simply rotate the "chart" circle.

```css
.pie .background {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#eaeaea;
  stroke-width:3;
  stroke-dasharray:100.53 100.53;
}

.pie .chart {
  fill:none;
  stroke:#f73319;
  stroke-width:3;
  stroke-dasharray:0 100.53;
  animation: 2s linear slice ;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

.pie text {
  font-size:6px;
}

@keyframes slice {
  to{stroke-dasharray:75.39 100.53;}
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
    <circle class="background" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%"/>
    <circle class="chart" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%"
            transform="rotate(-90 32 32)"/>
    <text x="32" y="32">
        75%
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution :)

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

OP does not prefer placing style in markup such as the previous example of using [presentation attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute#Presentation_attributes). I agree, SVG is ugly to begin with why make it uglier? If you are using a real SVG file rather than an embed in HTML...

1. You could use on external CSS stylesheet by using this `<?xml...` format:

   ```
     <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
   ```
2. Or you can use a `<style ...<![CDATA[...` block:

   ```
     <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
          .pie .txt {
             fill: red;
             font-family: Consolas;
             font-size: 14px;
             transform: rotate(90deg);
           }
        ]]>
      </style>
   ```
3. If it's an embed, a normal `<style>` block should work:

   ```
     <style>
       .pie .txt {
           fill: red;
           font-family: Consolas;
           font-size: 14px;
           transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
      </style>
   ```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kUAmSPAxsMAsOxGIPQtR?p=preview) that uses the most simplest option, number 3.

- I removed `transform-origin: 50% 50%;` because HTML starts in the middle, but SVG uses X, Y coords of (0,0) to start out usually. It might be anywhere but where I think it is, so I avoided it.
- Used the `fill` property.
- Added `.txt` class to `<text>` element.

---

### OLD

You can use presentation attributes:

```
<text x="25" y="12.5" fill="red" transform="rotate(90 20,20)" style="font-family:Consolas;font-size:10">
```

#### SNIPPET

```css
            .pie{
            border-radius:50%;
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
        .pie .background{
            fill:none;
            stroke:#eaeaea;
            stroke-width:3;
            stroke-dasharray:100.53 100.53;
        }
         .pie .chart{
            fill:none;
            stroke:#f73319;
            stroke-width:3;
            stroke-dasharray:0 100.53;
            animation: 2s linear slice ;
            animation-fill-mode:forwards;

        }
       /*  .pie .txt {
            fill:red;
            font-family: Consolas;
            font-size:14px;
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            
         }*/
        @keyframes slice{
            to{stroke-dasharray:75.39 100.53;}
        }
```

```html
<body>
<svg viewBox="0 0 64 64" class="pie">
    <circle class="background" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%">

    </circle>
       <circle class="chart" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%">

    </circle>
        <text x="25" y="12.5" fill="red" transform="rotate(90 20,20)" style="font-family:Consolas;font-size:10">

          75%
    </text>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: any reason why it works inline but not via css? it's not as pretty.