# How do I make Pomodoro clock like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would you go about making a Pomodoro clock like this:

[image]

Also as the time passes arrow would keep moving on causing circumference of circle to increase.

What approach/library would you use?
I am not asking for full solution but would be much helpful if you could give idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by looking at this answer:

[SVG circle animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178095/svg-circle-animation)

Combine that with a simple timer and you're on a good road.