# Animate radius in svg with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, donut-chart

I am trying to create an svg donut chart with vanilla JS. I was able to animate the fill stroke, though I want a pointer that starts from the center and goes to circumference to animate along with the value of donut. I could write a function to draw in the pointer but cannot come up with something to animate it.

[image: Donut animation]

My JS goes something like:

```
var svgCircle = document.querySelector('.progress');
var progressValue = document.querySelector('.progress__value');

var RADIUS = 108;
var CIRCUMFERENCE = 2 * Math.PI * RADIUS;

function progress(value) {
  var progress = value / 100;
  var dashoffset = CIRCUMFERENCE * (1 - progress);
  var innerCircle = drawInnerCircle();
  var handOfTheKing = drawHand(value);

  progressValue.style.strokeDashoffset = dashoffset;
  svgCircle.appendChild(handOfTheKing);

  svgCircle.appendChild(innerCircle);

}

function drawInnerCircle () {
  var innerCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','circle');
  innerCircle.setAttribute("id", "innerCircle");
  innerCircle.setAttribute("cx", "120");
  innerCircle.setAttribute("cy", "120");
  innerCircle.setAttribute("r", '10');
  innerCircle.setAttribute("stroke-width", '1');
  innerCircle.setAttribute("stroke", '#000');
  innerCircle.setAttribute("fill", '#fff');
  return innerCircle;
}

function drawHand(per) {
  var anglePartition = 2*Math.PI/100;
  var percentageWithOffset = per;
  var x = 120 + (120 * Math.cos(anglePartition * percentageWithOffset));
  var y = 120 + 120 * Math.sin(anglePartition * percentageWithOffset);
  var clockHand = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path');
  clockHand.setAttribute("id", "clockHand");
  clockHand.setAttribute("d", "M 120 120 L" + x + " " + y);
  clockHand.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
  clockHand.setAttribute("stroke-width", '1');
  return clockHand;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle for this.](https://jsfiddle.net/adfiddle/3rsmvpgq/1/)

Can anyone help?
TIA

EDIT: 
I want help with animating the arrow hand, not the donut fill stroke.

[image: What's needed]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG circle animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178095/svg-circle-animation)

Comment: Nope. I am trying to animate the radius arrow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178095/svg-circle-animation deals with the circle fill stroke animation which I'm already done with. Thanks for the link though :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mix two different types of animation. strokeDashoffset can be controlled through css animation, where as the path for the clock hand needs a linear interpretation of function which will calculate the radius at a time, which can't be done in css. While there might be different solutions to this problem. I have come up with this solution, see if it helps.

I am using requestAnimationFrame to do the same thing that you are doing through css transitions. I have included InOutQuad as easing function (https://github.com/component/ease/blob/master/index.js). Feel free to use whatever easing function you like.

```
    var control = document.getElementById('control');
    var svgCircle = document.querySelector('.progress');
    var progressValue = document.querySelector('.progress__value');

    var RADIUS = 108;
    var CIRCUMFERENCE = 2 * Math.PI * RADIUS;
    progressValue.style.strokeDashoffset = CIRCUMFERENCE;    

    function drawInnerCircle () {

      var innerCircle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','circle');
      innerCircle.setAttribute("id", "innerCircle");
      innerCircle.setAttribute("cx", "120");
      innerCircle.setAttribute("cy", "120");
      innerCircle.setAttribute("r", '10');
      innerCircle.setAttribute("stroke-width", '1');
      innerCircle.setAttribute("stroke", '#000');
      innerCircle.setAttribute("fill", '#fff');
      return innerCircle;
    }

   progressValue.style.strokeDasharray = CIRCUMFERENCE;

    var starttime

    function plot(timestamp, dist, duration){
      var timestamp = timestamp || new Date().getTime();
      var runtime = timestamp - starttime;
      var progress = runtime / duration;
      progress = inOutQuad(Math.min(progress, 1));

      //clock handle animation
      var anglePartition = 2*Math.PI/100;
      var percentageWithOffset = (dist * progress);
      var x = 120 + (120 * Math.cos(anglePartition * percentageWithOffset));
      var y = 120 + 120 * Math.sin(anglePartition * percentageWithOffset);
      var clockHand = document.getElementById('clockHand')
        clockHand.setAttribute("d", "M 120 120 L" + x + " " + y);
      clockHand.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
      clockHand.setAttribute("stroke-width", '1');

      //arc animation
      progressValue.style.strokeDashoffset = CIRCUMFERENCE * (1 - (progress * dist /100));
      if (runtime < duration){ 
        requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp){ 
          plot(timestamp, dist, duration)
        })
      }
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
         requestAnimationFrame(function(timestamp){
        starttime = timestamp || new Date().getTime();
        var innerCircle = drawInnerCircle();
        svgCircle.appendChild(innerCircle);
        plot(timestamp, 60, 1000);
      })
    }, 500)

    function inOutQuad(n){
            n *= 2;
        if (n < 1) return 0.5 * n * n;
        return - 0.5 * (--n * (n - 2) - 1);
        };
```

Here is a fiddle for the same https://jsfiddle.net/Ljvbx1hz/